# Cordova check close app event and save date/time

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

when my users pause their app, I save the date in a `window.localStorage` object so that when the app gets resumed I can send a request to my server and see if there are new messages for them. this works but when they close the app and restart, I need to set the date again so I can't check if there are messages between the time they closed it and restarted, since this is different from pause and resume.  here's a code sample to show a bit what I mean.

This is when the app get's started:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    var now = new Date();
    var year =   now.getFullYear();
    var month =   now.getMonth() + 1;
    var days =   now.getDate();
    var hours =   now.getHours();
    var minutes =   now.getMinutes();
    var seconds =   now.getSeconds();
    var now = year + '-' + month + '-' + days + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds; 
    window.localStorage.setItem('lastActive',now);

});
```

And these are the onpause/resume functions

```
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);


function onResume() {
    if(window.localStorage.getItem('lastActive')){
        var lastActive = window.localStorage.getItem('lastActive');
        console.log('last seen on: '+lastActive);
        $http({method: 'get', url: '***/api.php/inbox/'+window.localStorage.getItem('auth')+'/'+lastActive}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if(data.new < 1){
                $scope.newcount = data.new
            }else{
                $scope.newcount = data.new
            }
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $cordovaToast.showShortTop("are you connected to the internet?").then(function(success) {

            }, function (error) {
                alert("are you connected to the internet?");
            });
        }); 
    }else{
        console.log('lastst online: unkown');
    }
}

function onPause() {
    var now = new Date();
    var year =   now.getFullYear();
    var month =   now.getMonth() + 1;
    var days =   now.getDate();
    var hours =   now.getHours() + 1;
    var minutes =   now.getMinutes();
    var seconds =   now.getSeconds();
    var now = year + '-' + month + '-' + days + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds; 

    window.localStorage.setItem('lastActive',now);
    window.localStorage.setItem('lastActivejs',new Date());
}
```

now when the app get's closed, the ionicplatform.ready function get's fired again to set the last active date since i can't set one on close. i'm sure someone else had to deal with this and would like to know how you tackled it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be ideal for you but I got around this by setting the current time to `localStorage` once a minute, then when my app is opened the first thing my `ready()` function does is check the difference between  the `localStorage` value and `Date.now()`. This sounds like a performance killer but it works fine **in my app** – best to test in yours before relying on it. I do it thus:

```
function ticker() {
  var n=Date.now();
  if (n%60000<20) {
    localStorage.setItem("last_tick",n);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(ticker);
}
```

Call `ticker()` to start it going. `requestAnimationFrame()` allows the browser to optimise. However, if your app goes into the background, the WebKit engine will slow down the frequency at which `ticker()` will be called and may stop it altogether so you may find you need to use `setInterval()`, which may bring its own performance problems (although I still think it would be fine). Your question was how did other people get around this and this is what works for me.

Comment: Thanks, gonna try it out but i probably need to remove my date format or it will kill my performance

Comment: You mean in your `onPause` function? If so yes, I would store your localStorage string as simply the value returned by Date.now(). You can do all the format processing on retrieval.

Comment: Come to think of it, a simple `setInterval(localStorageSettingFunction, 60000)` might be your best bet.

Comment: messed around with it for a bit and found a way to use it without killing performance, thanks!

Comment: No problem, if I ever discover a less hacky way to do it in my own app I'll post it here, but it'll probably always depend on the cordova API. There might be a native plugin that can run code after the user closes your app but before the app is actually closed by the OS, but I haven't been able to find one with a quick google.

Comment: Me neither, the other events were described in the cordova documentation so if there was one they would probably include it in there